# Python 3 - return value from function

Tags: windows, python-3.x

I receive error while trying return value from a function 
say's dg isn't defined can you tell what's wrong ?

```
ipl = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
seg1,seg2,seg3,seg4=ipl.split(".")
ip2 = seg1+"."+seg2+"."+seg3+"."
ip3 = seg1+"."+seg2+"."+seg3+"."


def getDGW(ip3):
    cmd = 'ipconfig'
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd , stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in p.stdout:
        x = re.findall('Default Gateway',str(line))
        if x:
            regex = ip3 + r'[0-9]+'
            line = re.search(regex, str(line))
            if line:
                print(line.group(0))
                dg = line.group(0)
                return (dg)

getDGW(ip3)

print(dg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not in returning `dg`, but in the statement `print(dg)`. You want to have `print(getDGW(ip3))` or

```
dg = getDGW(ip3)
print(dg)
```

`dg` is an undefined variable outside of the scope of the function.